# assembly BYTE PTR clarification

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86

I'm working through some practice problems, and I'm stuck on one particular thing:

What is the decimal value in BYTE PTR value+2?

```
.data
list     DWORD 50 DUP(?)
matrix   DWORD 20 DUP(5 DUP(?))
value    DWORD 10597059    ; decimalstring
BYTE     "Computer Architecture",0
```

The base address of list is `1000H`.

I know the answer is 161, but I'm not sure how to get to that spot. Can anyone help explain that process? (there is extra data info in there from other questions using the same data set, fyi).

Thanks!

Comment: Please properly format your code. You've got words squished together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `value` has the decimal value of `10597059` - which is the DWORD value `00A1B2C3` in hexadecimal. Now, because the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) architecture is of [little-endian format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), this value is stored in reverse order in memory:

```
0  1  2  3                      0  1  2  3    ( position )                     
00 A1 B2 C3  will be stored as  C3 B2 A1 00   ( value )
```

Here you can see that the single BYTE value pointed to by `BYTE PTR value+2` is `A1` hexadecimal = 161 decimal. Because `BYTE PTR value` points to the BYTE at position 0 and `BYTE PTR value+2` points to the BYTE at position 2(relative to `value`), in the above illustration (the right one is how it is stored in memory). These BYTEs pointed to are only *one quarter* of the DWORD `value`, directly addressed.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that `BYTE PTR` means it's a reference to just that one byte, as opposed to `WORD PTR value+2` which would be the last 2 bytes (high half) of the value.